# Finding marginal cdf of $X$ from conditional cdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

Given $Y$, the conditional cdf of $X$ is $F_{X|Y}(x|y)=\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2$, where $x\leq y$. If $Y$ is exponentially distributed with intensity $\lambda$, what is the marginal cdf of $X$?

My approach is the followings:
$$F_{X}(x) =\int^{\infty}_{x} \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2 \cdot f_Y{\left(y\right)}dy$$
$$=\int^{\infty}_{x} \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2 \lambda \exp \{ -\lambda y \} dy$$

However, it seems to be false. How do i obtain the marginal cdf of $X$?

============================[ Update ]===============================

From the references, I know that

$$f_X(x)= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f_{X,Y}\left( x,y\right) dy,$$
$$f_{X|Y}\left(x|y\right)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}.$$

Therefore, in my opinion, $f_{X|Y}\left(x|y\right){f_Y(y)}= f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

Now, I further suppose that,
$$f_{X|Y}\left(x|y\right)= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0 && x<0 \\ 
\frac{2x}{y^2} && 0 \leq x \leq y \\ 
0 && y < x
\end{array},
\right. 
$$ 
and

$$f_Y \left( y\right)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
0 && y \leq 0 \\ 
\lambda \exp \{-\lambda y \} && 0 \leq y \\ 
\end{array}.
\right.
$$
Therefore, I assume that 
$$
\begin{array}{c}
f_X(x) && = && \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)~dy \\
&& = && \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f_{X|Y}\left(x|y\right){f_Y(y)}~dy\\
&& = && \int^{\infty}_{x} \frac{2\lambda x}{y^2}  \exp \{-\lambda y \}~dy
.
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c}
F_X(c) && = && \int^{c}_{0} \int^{\infty}_{x} \frac{2\lambda x}{y^2}  \exp \{-\lambda y \}~dy~dx
.
\end{array}
$$ 
This is the correct answer.

Comment: What does make you think that the first result you wrote is wrong? Could you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain the marginal CDF of $X$ by first computing the marginal pdf of $X$ and then integrating to get the marginal CDF. So, the conditional CDF of $X$ given that $Y = y$ where $y \geq 0$ is
$$F_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y) = \begin{cases}0, &x < 0, \\ \displaystyle\left(\frac xy\right)^2, &0 \leq x < y, \\1, &x\geq y.\end{cases}$$
Can you determine $f_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y)$ from this? How about $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$?

Comment: I guess $f_{X|Y}\left( x|y\right)=\frac{2x}{y^2}$ for $0 \leq x \leq y$ and zero elsewhere, whereas
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int^{\infty}_x \frac{2x}{y^2}\lambda \exp\{-\lambda y\}dy$. Is this correct?

Comment: _Read_ what your book says about the relationship between $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Y)$ and $f_Y(y)$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ once again, and be sure to write down the regions where various expressions for $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ are valid.

Comment: I'm actually bit confused with the region. Here's how I understand the problem. We can obtain $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ by taking the derivative of $F_{X|Y}(x|y)$ w.r.t. to $x$. Since Y is an exponential random variable with intensity $\lambda$, we thus have $f_{Y}(y)=\lambda \exp \{-\lambda y \}$. The region is where I'm confused since it supposed to be $0$ to $\infty$, but the conditional pdf is $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{2x}{y^2}$ for $0 \leq x \leq y$ and zero elsewhere, which implies that $y$ must be greater than $x$. Therefore, i feel we have to intergrate from $x$ to $\infty$

Comment: OK, it is time for harsher words. **Read** what your book says is the relationship between $f_{X\mid Y}(x,y)$, $f_Y(y)$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. It is **NOT** the integral formula that you write, and if your book tells you it _is_ the integral that you have written, **throw away that book** and find another one. Note that the integral that you have written results in a function of $x$ alone; not a function of _both_ $x$ and $y$. That $y$ disappears when you substitute the limits making the result a function of $x$ alone.

Comment: See update. Kindly advise.

Comment: The integration is correct. Thanks for the enlightenment.